# Trying to connect to EC2 (g4dn) instance via SSH timing out

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm having trouble launching an EC2 instance and connecting to it via SSH - specifically I'm getting "Operation timeout" errors.

I'm attempting to run on a g4dn instance with the following AMI (if it's relevant - I suspect it might be, as I'm not having any issues with a t2.micro instance with the default AMI):

Deep Learning AMI GPU PyTorch 2.0.1 (Amazon Linux 2) 20230627 ami-051619310404cab17

EDIT: This is a bit of a red herring, I think - I seem to be getting issues with the default AMI also (that lets me connect fine on t2 instances).

The command

`nc -vz <public IP>.compute-1.amazonaws.com 22`

gives me

`nc: connectx to <public IP>.compute-1.amazonaws.com port 22 (tcp) failed: Operation timed out`

I've confirmed that (as far as I can tell) my security group and NACLs are configured properly, and I'm not running any firewalls. As mentioned, if I try to run a t2.micro instance with the default AMI and I use the same security group then things seem to launch fine, and I can SSH without issue.

Again apologies if I've overlooked anything obvious... Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: There are a few items to check: 
1. Security Group to open port 22 to your IP
2. That your instance is in the public subnet
3. You need to pass the username@hostIP and use your pem file to authenticate

Comment: Do different AMIs work?

Comment: @user253751 good question - they don't seem to, no. When I spin up a t2 instance using ami-0005e0cfe09cc9050 I can SSH no troubles, and when I spin up a g4dn instance with this AMI and try to SSH I get the timeout error.

Comment: @mlim1972 as far as I can tell I've done all these but am still facing issues I'm afraid!

Comment: Okay for extra info - I p3 and t2 instances let me SSH fine - g4dn are the only ones I've tried that are giving me issues.

Comment: As an experiment, I wonder if you can take an instance that allows SSH, then stop it, change the instance type to `g4dn`, start it again and try to connect?